# A resource for learning ACME

Tags: architecture

I need to learn ACME (An Architecture Description Language developed at Carnegie Mellon University) in a short time for my school project. Could you introduce a useful and comprehensive resource to me.

Comment: Why the official website (http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~acme/docs/index.html) is not enough for you?

Comment: What kind of resources are you looking for beyond the existing documentation?

Answer (score 3):

Although it's quite influential in academic circles, there isn't really a single good references on ACME for someone who wants to use it.

As darlinton says, the language overview on the official site is a good starting point: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~acme/docs/language_overview.html

You could also download ACME Studio (http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~acme/AcmeStudio/index.html) and follow the tutorials.  That will help you understand the language constructs.

There is also the original paper defining the language, published as a CMU technical report: http://repository.cmu.edu/tepper/322 (and you'll find some more ACME case studies and related work there).